# Calculating font size on UILabel after adjusting it to fit width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uilabel

I need to implement the code which will equalise font sizes between multiple UILabel's - for this I need to find smallest font size that will be visible from group of those UILabel's and apply it to the rest of them.

Here is the code I'm using to calculate actual font size of UILabel after font get's scale to fit it's width:

```
NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
context.minimumScaleFactor = label.minimumScaleFactor;
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : label.font};
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:label.text attributes:attributes];
[attributedString boundingRectWithSize:label.bounds.size
                                       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       context:context];

CGFloat actualFontSize = label.font.pointSize * context.actualScaleFactor;
```

The problem is it works on for multiline `UILabel`.
After I try to use it on `UILabel` which has `numberOfLines = 1` it is going crazy and giving me always original font size.

I tried removing `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin` from options - but it is still giving me wrong results.

Does anyone encounter this problem or maybe you have different ways of getting the final font size after fitting to width ?